# Having issue with state variable in react js. Cannot update the variable's value to true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, es6-promise

```
import getAuthentication from './getAuthentication';

 class Home extends React. Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        //this.authentication = false;
        this.state = {
          username: '',
          password: '',
          check:false,
          authentication:false
        };
        this.err = '';
      }



      componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log (this.state.authentication);
        console.log(this.state.authentication == true);

    if (this.state.check)
    {
        const promiseAuthentication = getAuthentication(
          this.state.username,
          this.state.password,
        );
        promiseAuthentication
          .then(response => {
            console.log (response.data.Success);
            console.log(response.data.Success == true);
            this.setState({check :false, authentication:response.data.Success});

          })
          .catch(error => {
            // console.log(error);
            this.err = error;
          });

      }

      if (this.state.authentication == true) {
        event.preventDefault();
        history.push('/overview');
       } 

      }

      assignUsername = event => {
        this.setState({ username: event.target.value });
      };

      assignPassword = event => {
        this.setState({ password: event.target.value });
      };

      handleSubmit = () => {
        this.setState({ check:true });
      };
==============================================================

getAuthentication.js

import axios from 'axios';

function getAuthentication(username, password) {
  const authenticationConfig = {
    Email: username,
    Password: password,
  };
  return axios.post(
    'http://localhost:5002/login/confirmation',
    authenticationConfig,
  );
}

export default getAuthentication;
```

In the above code my `this.state.Authentication` is not getting updated to `true`

I am trying to update its value in axios promise.

Can someone please tell me what's wrong? I mean I have tried everything but I am not able to proceed.

How do I change the state of Authentication object and switch new window?

I have a second file that is returning the axios promise where promise value is "undefined".. How do I make async call and resolve this issue ??

Comment: are you getting any errors in console ?

Comment: I suspect you should use `componentDidMount` in this case. `componentDidUpdate` will be triggered only when the component Updates. Did you try that?
Below is from reactJS docs: 
`You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note that it must be wrapped in a condition * if (this.props.userID !== prevProps.userID) *`

Comment: Can provide reaming code?

Comment: can you please check if getAuthentication function is returning a promise which is resolved. because you might not be resolving the promise and it never enters in then call

Comment: I have updated the post with my whole code. 1) I just want to get username and password from the form 2) call the server for authentication 3) if the server says okay then I change the view using history function.

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidUpdate` is wrapped in `if (this.state.check)`. Nothing in the code you pasted sets `this.state.check` to true.  Set `this.state.check: true`.

Comment: i am updating the check variable via setState function in handleSubmit function

Comment: What calls `handleSubmit`? Nothing in the code you posted

Comment: Its getting called from a form in the render function  <form className={s.form} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

Comment: Then you need to bind the `this` of `handleSubmit`.  In Home's constructor, `this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)`

Comment: I am doing that in the constructor as well